# Php associative array for offset from 1 to 26

Tags: php

I am trying to create an associative array with alphabets as keys and 1 to 26 as values which I need to use to find the offset of alphabet from 1. So array['a'] would give me 1 and array['c'] would give me 3. Is there a way to declare such an array without typing in all characters 1 by 1 as in

array('a' => 1, 'b' =>2, 'c'=>3 .... and so on

Or is there another way to get offset for alphabet from 1 to 26

Comment: If I may ask: For what do you need this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) and [`range()`](http://php.net/range):

```
array_combine(range('a', 'z'), range(1, 26));
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to build the array, use like following -

```
$index = ord($input_char) - ord('a') + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chr` and `ord`:

```
chr(97);  // a
chr(122); // z
ord('a'); // 97
ord('z'); // 122

arr = array();
for($i=1; $i<=26; ++$i) {
    arr(chr(96+$i)) = $i;
}
```

Comment: I think OP was asking for `a` to `z`, not `A` to `Z`.